# Gallery of galleries in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I need to do this:
http://www.somethingdesign.com/press.html

But I don't see how I can do it in wordpress, I've tried Nextgen plugin but the gallery shows all the images and the album is only a link to the gallery and I don't want this effect.

Anybody knows any way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776032/is-there-a-wordpress-plugin-for-gallery-of-galleries) stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

if made out of images, how you want to store text info? I suggest make out of post, then use for. ex.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/so-masonry/